# Creating EMR Cluster based on AMI using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-emr

I have a custom AMI.I want to create an EMR Cluster based on that AMI using boto3.
I checked the documentation , found CLI version but didnt find about boto3 version.

CLI Version :

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Cluster with My Custom AMI" \
--custom-ami-id MyAmiID --ebs-root-volume-size 20 \
--release-label emr-5.7.0 --use-default-roles \
--instance-count 2 --instance-type m5.xlarge
```

Can anyone please help ?
Thanks.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Yes @Marcin , still unclear of how to start a new EMR Cluster with "Custom AMI" using run_job_flow.Would really appreciate your help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In boto3 you use [run_job_flow](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow) to create new cluster:

> RunJobFlow creates and starts running a **new cluster** (job flow).

Comment: Thanks for the link.Can we create EMR Cluster using our own custom AMI ?